# Deleting a node from a filtered DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList does not change focus to the following visible node

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, treelist

I am using a `DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList` v10.2 control which is populated with more `TreeListNode`.

Suppose I am filtering the `TreeList`. Now I only have the filtered `TreeListNode(s)`.

Next, if I decide to **remove** one node, which is normally followed by other nodes that are not visible in my filtered tree, then no other node gets **focused**.

If the node I remove is followed by another node which is visible in the filtered tree, then this works fine, as the node following the node I have just removed gets selected.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050354/devexpress-xtratreelist-problem-with-focusing-node-that-is-invisible).

Hope that helps !

Comment: According to https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q589677 this issue is fixed on the new version.